# Iterating a ToggleGroup and setting each ToggleButton's properties

Tags: java, javafx, iteration, togglebutton

I can't figure out how to get this to work.  I'm trying to go through each of the buttons in a ToggleGroup to set their properties (e.g., visible, disabled), but having no luck. There seems to be no way to set the ToggleGroup as a whole.

I've tried several ways to do it, but have had no luck. ToggleGroup's methods only allow for a getToggles(), so I figured that is how I'm going to have to work at this.

```
mainToggleGroup.getToggles().stream().forEach((button) -> {
    button.setVisible(false);
});
```

Closest I've gotten, but the button doesn't have any methods to allow me to change the properties.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found my problem just as I was about to submit this! I needed to cast the getToggles result over from a Toggle to a ToggleButton.

```
mainToggleGroup.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton)toggle).forEach((button) -> {
    button.setVisible(false);
});
```

This seems to work, but is this the proper way to do this?

Comment: ToggleGroup could have a generic type parameter e.g. `ToggleGroup<T extends Toggle>`, then you could declare `ToggleGroup<ToggleButton> toggles = new ToggleGroup<>();` and everything subsequently wouldn't need explicit casts - you could create a [feature request](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: The map isn't strictly necessary, you can write: `toggles.getToggles().stream().forEach(toggle -> ((ToggleButton) toggle).setVisible(false))`